# Datatable works fine on local but on production i have error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, yajra-datatable

I have an issue when I put Laravel app on production server with Yajra Datatables. I have strange issue Invalid JSON response with status code 200 in my debug. This extension works fine on my local Linux server but in production I have this error and i can't find any solution. Please any help.
This is my code.

```
   var table = $("#excel_table").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": "500px",
        "paging": "true",
        'dom': 'Rlfrtip',
        'colReorder': {
            'allowReorder': false
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{ route('admin.getdata') }}",
            "type": "POST",

        },

        "columns": [
            {
                'data': 'id',
                'name': 'id',
                'visible': false
            },
            {
                'data': 'action',
                'name': 'action'
            },
            {
                'data': 'kw',
                'name': 'kw'
            },
            {
                'data': 'startdatum',
                'name': 'startdatum'
            },
            {
                'data': 'enddatum',
                'name': 'enddatum'
            }]
          )}
```

Comment: We need to see the response from `route('admin.getdata')` in production to help. The error you're getting has to do with the data coming out of the production database. If it's not valid JSON (you say Invalid JSON response with status code 200), then what is it? Check out the Network tab of your browser dev tools.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=excel_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1       I got this response but there is no error in network tab, this is post route and server returns it with status code 200, datatables are loaded properly. I don't know where is issue.

Comment: You want to go to Chrome Dev Tools -> Network Tab -> Click on the POST request to admin.getdata -> then click on the Response sub-tab. That will show you the data your server is sending to datatables. The datatables error you are seeing says "This isn't valid JSON, I don't know what to do". So, the question we ask now is "Well, if it's not valid JSON, then what is it?".

Comment: Check out this picture: https://ibb.co/1fXNRrs

Comment: I solved my issue with VPS. Everything works fine on VPS. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Debug from the console and network tab from your browser.
1. Check the Yajra Datatables script loaded properly or not on the production
2. Check the Yajra Datatables needs any extra extension or not. Debug this on the network section on chrome debug.
3. Check the response on the network see what is the response on this request (Please APP Debug TRUE from .env before debugging)

Comment: All scripts are loaded correctly, and returns response from POST route with 200 code, but I don't see any error in network tab to debug. Debug is set to true but there is no error showing from DB or from routes. I am confused about this error. I am using shared hosting for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue when i changed my hosting. I was on shared hosting and when I changed to VPS everything works fine.